# Multiple Assignment of more than one variable sql server select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Can I assign multiple variables under a single condition in a select statement in SQL Server (I am too stupid for dynamic sql):

For example in Visual Basic or many other languages you might have

If x=1 then 
    z=4
    y=2
End if

I don't think CASE works, because I think you can only assign to one variable.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is that if you can get away with the assignments on one line, then you dont need BEGIN/END block as the other person has suggested. Although things will start to look ugly.  Here's some examples that achieve what you want:

```
-- using set syntax on one line
declare @x int, @y int , @z int
set @x=1
IF @x=1 set @y=2 set @z=4
print 'y:' + cast(@y as varchar) + ' z:' + cast(@z as varchar)
GO

-- using select syntax, a little prettier on one line
declare @x int, @y int , @z int
set @x=1
IF @x=1 SELECT @y=2,@z=4
print  'y:' + cast(@y as varchar) + ' z:' + cast(@z as varchar)
GO
-- using being/end
declare @x int, @y int , @z int
set @x=1
IF @x=1 
BEGIN
    set @y=2
    set @z=4
END
print 'y:' + cast(@y as varchar) + ' z:' + cast(@z as varchar)
```

Comment: Just [please don't cast as varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the assignments in BEGIN... END